# How to get `SourceDir` folder and `Drop Folder` while in C# customized activity code of TFS 2012 build process template?

Tags: c#, path, workflow-activity, build-process-template

I'm writing a customized activity for TFS build process workflow, e.g. guideline [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx).

In my C# CodeActivity .Execute() method, I want to access to `SourceDir` folder and `Drop Folder`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the information which you need as arguments, e.g. `SourcesDiriectory` for your `SourceDir` and `BuildDetail.DropLocation` for your `DropFolder` to your activity.

Comment: What value to pass to it then?

Comment: BuildDetail.DropLocation and "SourcesDirectory"